# what does the function iloc do in the iris dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

Can someone explain what the bolded portions of this code. I have read the documentation for pandas and sklearn and it is still a bit hard to wrap my mind around it. I am wanting to modify this for my own data and would like to understand this a bit more.

```
X = df.iloc[0:100, **[0,1]**].values
plt.scatter(**X[:50, 0], X[:50, 1]**,alpha=0.5, c='b', edgecolors='none', label='setosa %2s'%(y[0]))
plt.scatter(**X[50:100, 0], X[50:100, 1]**,alpha=0.5, c='r', edgecolors='none', label='versicolor %2s'%(y[50]))
```

Full code below

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing
from mlclass2 import simplemetrics, plot_decision_2d_lda

df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/'
        'machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data', header=None)
X = df.iloc[0:100, **[0,1]**].values
y = df.iloc[0:100, 4].values
y = np.where(y == 'Iris-setosa', 0, 1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=5)

stdscaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_scaled  = stdscaler.transform(X)
X_train_scaled = stdscaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled  = stdscaler.transform(X_test)

# plot data
plt.scatter(X[:50, 0], X[:50, 1],alpha=0.5, c='b', edgecolors='none', label='setosa %2s'%(y[0]))
plt.scatter(X[50:100, 0], X[50:100, 1],alpha=0.5, c='r', edgecolors='none', label='versicolor %2s'%(y[50]))
plt.xlabel('sepal length [cm]')
plt.ylabel('petal length [cm]')
plt.legend(loc='lower right')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) is only returning the values of the data frame with the axis labels removed.

.iloc uses integer-location based indexing.

The [.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) portion of code is saying that we need the first 100 rows of only column 0 and 1 for our independent variable and only the first 100 rows of row 4 for our dependent variable. If this part is still confusing, I recommend that you look into slice notation. Quickly put, the slice notation on the .iloc simplifys to .iloc[start:stop].

Original DataFrame:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import preprocessing


df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/'
        'machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data', header=None)
X = df.iloc[0:100, [0,1]].values
y = df.iloc[0:100, 4].values
y = np.where(y == 'Iris-setosa', 0, 1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=5)

stdscaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X_train)
X_scaled  = stdscaler.transform(X)
X_train_scaled = stdscaler.transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled  = stdscaler.transform(X_test)

print(df)
```

Output:

```py
       0    1    2    3               4
0    5.1  3.5  1.4  0.2     Iris-setosa
1    4.9  3.0  1.4  0.2     Iris-setosa
2    4.7  3.2  1.3  0.2     Iris-setosa
3    4.6  3.1  1.5  0.2     Iris-setosa
4    5.0  3.6  1.4  0.2     Iris-setosa
..   ...  ...  ...  ...             ...
145  6.7  3.0  5.2  2.3  Iris-virginica
146  6.3  2.5  5.0  1.9  Iris-virginica
147  6.5  3.0  5.2  2.0  Iris-virginica
148  6.2  3.4  5.4  2.3  Iris-virginica
149  5.9  3.0  5.1  1.8  Iris-virginica

[150 rows x 5 columns]
```

iloc[0:100, [0,1]].values - See how we are only return columns 0 and 1 here? Starting at index value 0 and ending at 100, [start:stop]. We are only selecting columns 0 and 1 because of [0,1] to be clear.

```
[[5.1 3.5]
 [4.9 3. ]
 [4.7 3.2]
 [4.6 3.1]
 [5.  3.6]
 [5.4 3.9]
 [4.6 3.4]
 [5.  3.4]
 [4.4 2.9]
 [4.9 3.1]
 [5.4 3.7]
 [4.8 3.4]
 [4.8 3. ]
 [4.3 3. ]
 [5.8 4. ]
 [5.7 4.4]
 [5.4 3.9]
 [5.1 3.5]
```

df.iloc[0:100, 4].values - Same as above but, only selecting column 4.

```
['Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa'
 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa'
 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa'
 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa'
 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa'
 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa' 'Iris-setosa']
```